# How can I show a message from server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am not a java developer, but my company purchase a product to handle their accounting stuff based on java. Now I am facing a problem because they want to prevent repeated invoices on the system and the software allows the user to do it. I called support and they suggested me to create a suppressed field on the client side, copy on that field the message I want to show and read that field when the user tab to the next field. those are a lot of steps and totally inefficient. Below is my code based on what they suggested. **It currently showed me the invoice exist message twice**.

**server side**

```
CSServer.log (Step)
  if ((CSEvent.getTarget().getName() == "InvoiceNumber") && (CSEvent.getAction() == "Tabout" ) && (Step == 0)) 
    {
      if (!cnn) 
      {
        CSServer.log ("GPCONNECT Lookup::CSForm_OnValidateLookup Connection to the database failed");
      } 
      else 
      {
        Sql  = "SELECT COUNT (*) as Result FROM [DYNAMICS].[dbo].[AP_Invoice_Table] WHERE [VendorID] = '" + CSForm.getField("VendorID").getValue() + "' and [DocumentNumber] = '" + CSForm.getField("InvoiceNumber").getValue()+"'";
        resultInvSet = cnn.executeSQL(Sql);
        var x =null;
        x = resultInvSet.getValue("Result");
      }
      if (x > 0) 
      {
        CSForm.getField("msg").setValue("Invoice number already exist, please check your entry!");
        return false;
      } 
      else
      {
        CSForm.getField("msg").setValue("");
      }
    }
```

**client side**

```
function InvoiceAmount_OnFocus()
{
  var m =CSForm.getField('msg').getValue();
  if (m != "")
  {
    $("#InvoiceNumber").focus();
    CSClient.alert(m);
    CSForm.getField("InvoiceNumber").setFillColor("FF0000");
  }
  else
  {
  CSForm.getField("InvoiceNumber").setFillColor("FFFFFF");
  }
  return true;
}
```

Could someone please showed me the right way to handle this?

**Update:**
Client and server use SOAP and HTTP call to communicate.

Comment: You can accomplish something like that using ajax

Comment: Is this application using SignalR or something similar for real-time two-way communication between the server and the client?

Comment: good question @HowardRenollet, let me ask to support

Comment: oh, you said Java, so it wouldn't be SignalR, but there are other libraries out there that support this type of communication.

Comment: I stand corrected, I guess Microsoft did release SignalR for Java and Android earlier this year.

Comment: support said no, they don't use any like that

Comment: How is CSForm defined client-side? And CSClient for that matter

Comment: just curious - is the `InvoiceAmount_OnFocus()` called twice? Inside the function you are calling `$("#InvoiceNumber").focus();`, I am not sure but does this invoke the method twice?

Comment: what does that is once the cursor hit invoice amount(field that follow invoice number on tab sequence) it will show the message depending on the Server side validation. If msg field is not in blank, it will mark the invoice number in red and put the focus on it. @ArinCool, but for some reason it is showing the message twice

Comment: can you comment this line and check
`$("#InvoiceNumber").focus();`

Comment: I did that and now I am getting message one time as desired, but it let me continue filling remaining info without correcting the invoice number @ArinCool

Comment: What is `CSServer`..? looks like you're missing important tags...

Comment: Csserver is c# based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a webmethod that you call via AJAX and pop the javascript alert based on the result of that function.

example (in your .aspx page):

```
        function doSomething(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Do_Something.aspx/DoSomething?id=" + id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
```

In Do_Something.aspx.cs:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string DoSomething(string id)
    {
        var docs = SqlHelper.SelectAllByInvoiceId(id);
        if (docs.Count > 0)
        {
            return "exists";
        }
        return "does not exist";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create AJAX function to talk to server side function.
Step 2: Return message from server side function and handle that in AJAX function (success or done).
Step 3: Alert message if ajax function catches any result.

For ajax implementation you can refer: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp
Or
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/